# Executando ação em uma ID não clicada

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Eu tenho vários links:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="ZoomPath" data-ref-id-map="Layer_1" data-ref-g-id="xxx">São Paulo - São Paulo</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="ZoomPath" data-ref-id-map="Layer_1" data-ref-g-id="yyy">São Paulo - Osasco</a>


<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="ZoomPath" data-ref-id-map="Layer_2" data-ref-g-id="xxx">São Paulo - São Paulo</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="ZoomPath" data-ref-id-map="Layer_2" data-ref-g-id="yyy">São Paulo - Osasco</a>
```

E tenho o código:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#ZoomPath', function(){

      var Mapa = $(this).attr('data-ref-id-map');
      var GID  = $(this).attr('data-ref-g-id');

      clicked(GID, Mapa);

      $("g#"+GID+' > path').each(function(){

        $(this).addClass('hover-map');

      });

      $("g#"+GID+' > path').each(function(){

      $(this).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover-map');
      });

      });

    });

function clicked(id_click, id_map) {

      var svgClicked = d3.select("svg#"+id_map);

      var bbox = d3.select("svg#"+id_map+" g#"+id_click).node().getBBox();

      var svgWidth = bbox.width;
      var svgHeight = bbox.height;

      var x = bbox.x-(280/2), //METADE DA LARGURA DO SVG /2
          y = bbox.y-(245/2); //METADE DA ALTURA DO SVG /2

      var scale = 2;

      svgClicked.transition().duration(2000)
          .call(zoom.translate([((x * -scale) + (svgWidth / 2)), ((y * -scale) + svgHeight / 2)])
          .scale(scale).event);
      }
```

O código acima deveria funcionar assim: Ao clicar em um link ele pega os atributos **data-ref-id-map** e **data-ref-g-id** e da um zoom no SVG (`data-ref-id-map`) que tem um path com a ID que está em `data-ref-g-map`. O problema é que ele só da zoom no SVG da ID **Layer_1**. Por mais que eu clique no link que contém o **Layer_2** ele está dando no outro SVG (Layer_1).

Fiz um debug para ver qual ID (layer) ele está passando na função `clicked` e ele passa a ID (layer) certa, no caso **Layer_2**

Answer (score 2):

O erro está na repetição de **ID**, só deve se utilizar um **ID** para cada elemento, apesar de não dar um erro imediato, o erro ocorre na execução das ações, no caso o javascript ta lendo o id do primeiro elemento, msm vc clicando em um elemento posterior.

Sugiro que faça o seguinte:

ou define um id para cada click, ex:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="ZoomPath1" data-ref-id-map="Layer_1" data-ref-g-id="xxx">São Paulo - São Paulo</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="ZoomPath2" data-ref-id-map="Layer_1" data-ref-g-id="yyy">São Paulo - Osasco</a>


<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="ZoomPath3" data-ref-id-map="Layer_2" data-ref-g-id="xxx">São Paulo - São Paulo</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="ZoomPath4" data-ref-id-map="Layer_2" data-ref-g-id="yyy">São Paulo - Osasco</a>
```

ou se isso for muito complicado devido a quantidade de elementos, ao invés de tratar por id, passar a tratar por class. Ex:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ZoomPath" data-ref-id-map="Layer_1" data-ref-g-id="xxx">São Paulo - São Paulo</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ZoomPath" data-ref-id-map="Layer_1" data-ref-g-id="yyy">São Paulo - Osasco</a>


<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ZoomPath" data-ref-id-map="Layer_2" data-ref-g-id="xxx">São Paulo - São Paulo</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ZoomPath" data-ref-id-map="Layer_2" data-ref-g-id="yyy">São Paulo - Osasco</a>
```

e aqui, vc muda o **#** por **.**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.ZoomPath', function(){
```

**Atualizando**

dei uma conferida em algumas coisas, e refiz seu código. Faz um teste e me diz por favor.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ZoomPath" data-map="Layer_1" data-g="xxx">São Paulo - São Paulo</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ZoomPath" data-map="Layer_1" data-g="yyy">São Paulo - Osasco</a>


    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ZoomPath" data-map="Layer_2" data-g="xxx">São Paulo - São Paulo</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ZoomPath" data-map="Layer_2" data-g="yyy">São Paulo - Osasco</a>

$(document).on('click', 'a.ZoomPath', function(){

      var Mapa = $(this).data('map');
      var GID  = $(this).data('g');

      clicked(GID, Mapa);

      $("g#"+GID+' > path').each(function(){

        $(this).addClass('hover-map');

      });

      $("g#"+GID+' > path').each(function(){

      $(this).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover-map');
      });

      });

    });

function clicked(id_click, id_map) {

      var svgClicked = d3.select("svg#"+id_map);

      var bbox = d3.select("svg#"+id_map+" g#"+id_click).node().getBBox();

      var svgWidth = bbox.width;
      var svgHeight = bbox.height;

      var x = bbox.x-(280/2), //METADE DA LARGURA DO SVG /2
          y = bbox.y-(245/2); //METADE DA ALTURA DO SVG /2

      var scale = 2;

      svgClicked.transition().duration(2000)
          .call(zoom.translate([((x * -scale) + (svgWidth / 2)), ((y * -scale) + svgHeight / 2)])
          .scale(scale).event);
      }
```

Comment: mudei para *class* e não funcionou também @LuizAugustoNeto

Comment: PRecisa mudar essa linha:

$(document).on('click', 'a#ZoomPath', function(){

Para essa:

$(document).on('click', 'a.ZoomPath', function(){ 

Já que agora é uma class e não mais uma ID.

Comment: Verdade, eu n tinha reparado q tinha esquecido esse detalhe, legal @Ívini